# How can I limit the access to an IP address from the local network

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, vlan

In my local network, all PC's are connected in the same subnet (`192.168.0.x`).

[image]

I have a machine which is connected to switch B and it has been assigned with a static IP (e.g `192.168.0.10`). Any PC in the same local network can access it from the browser and see its menu. What I want is to limit the access to it, so certain PCs to be able to reach it.

How can I do this? For example I want the IP `192.168.0.10` to be visible only to PC with IP's `192.168.0.5` and `192.168.0.6`

The target machine(`192.168.0.10`) is a machine (in a factory) where I don't know what Web Server is running and if I can edit it settings..

Can I add a setting in the router?

Comment: You would use a *firewall* on the webserver host. The question is too vague to give a more specific answer. If you add your OS, someone could create a proper answer for you.

Comment: If the target machine is connected to switch A, *by design* there is nothing you can do to prevent computers from switch A to connect to it, unless you create another subnet. I am not even sure you could prevent machines from switch B to connect to it either (depends on the router).

Comment: You need separate subnets then. If security is a concern, they need to be physically (or at least via VLANs) separate, too.

Comment: Understood @DanielB Please post it as an answer to take the credits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most usual solution is to use the target's firewall. Here the "target" would be the machine with IP `192.168.0.10`. You need administrator access to this machine.

What you need to do is one of those:

- block all incoming connections originating from IPs that must not acces to the target
- allow only incoming connections originating from IPs that can access the target

---

E.G. on a *NIX machine, using `iptables`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.5 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.6 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

<s>Note that your question is extremely broad, so this answer may not be applicable.</s>

**EDIT**: given the additional info, this answer *is* not applicable.

Comment: You can always remove your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this on the router: there is just one subnet, so any traffic goes directly between the PCs, not through the router.

Your best option is to follow Nathan Shiraini's instruction and limit traffic on the target machine, rather then router.

Sure, there are other possibilities, i.e. add another subnet and route packets to that subnet through your router, but those are greatly depend on you router capabilities.

If the router you have is a casual home/small business router, most probably you will not be able to implements that scenario. If your router has few L3 (routing) interfaces or a dedicated DMZ port, or you are not using your WAN port, you might be able to connect the machine to that port there and limit traffic on the router.